# CSS @import from local extension file (shadow-dom)

Tags: html, css, import, shadow-dom

I'm implementing an extension and I use Shadow DOM. As injecting CSS to content and specifying `::shadow` attribute is deprecated, is there any other comfortable way, how to style the content? Not specifying the style manually inside like `<style>.myClass { ... }</style>`.

I tried:
        `'<style>@import url("'+chrome.extension.getURL('css/style.css')+'");</style>'`

but it does not work

Comment: Do you know that Chrome  extensions are also deprecated (excepting for ChromeOs)?

Comment: my aim is to develop cross-browser extension. Either way, it also does not work using `browser.extension.getURL('css/style.css')` (and yes, the file is declared in web_accessible_resoruces)

Comment: did you try `<style>@import url('/css/style.css')</style>`?

Comment: it won't work, since the CSS is injected into the webpage. The css file is inside the extension.